# Race condition on boolean written by callbacks and read within the activity

Tags: android, race-condition

From an Android activity I'm sending http requests driven by the user pressing buttons on the UI.
I don't want multiple requests running at the same time (OutlookClient crashes).

My question is: is it possible to have **race conditions** due to the callbacks with the results writing the same boolean (using runOnUiTread) that is read before sending a new request?

Thanks

```
// Should this be either "volatile" or atomic ??
private boolean isThereAPendingRequest = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    genericClient = clientInitializer.create(this);
    // ...

    isThereAPendingRequest = true; // still have to login

    Futures.addCallback(genericClient.logon(this, scopes), new FutureCallback<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {

            // ...
            isThereAPendingRequest = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {

            // ...
            isThereAPendingRequest = false;
        }
    });

    // ...
}

// ...

public void getBookings(View view){

    if(isThereAPendingRequest){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There's already a pending request. Try in a few seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    isThereAPendingRequest = true;

    Futures.addCallback( genericClient.getCalendarEvents(), new FutureCallback<List<List>>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final List<List> resultCalendars) {

            Log.d("APP", "Success. Result: "+resultCalendars);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // ..

                    isThereAPendingRequest = false;
            }
        }
    }
    // ..
}

public void sendBooking(View view){

    if(isThereAPendingRequest){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There's already a pending request. Try in a few seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    isThereAPendingRequest = true;

    Futures.addCallback( genericClient.sendBooking( booker, title), new FutureCallback<List<String>>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final List<String> resultBooking) {

              Log.d("APP", "Success. Result: "+resultBooking);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                      // ...
                      isThereAPendingRequest = false;
                    }
                });
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

           Log.e( "APP", "Delete error. Cause: "+t.getLocalizedMessage() );

           // ...

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           isThereAPendingRequest = false;
        }
   });

   }catch(Exception ex){
       // logger
       isThereAPendingRequest = false;
   }
}
```

UPDATE: this is one of the function called in the Futures..

```
public ListenableFuture<List<List>> getCalendarEvents(){

// logger

final SettableFuture<List<List>> future = SettableFuture.create();

DateTime now = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime workDayEnd = new DateTime( now.getYear(), now.getMonthOfYear(), now.getDayOfMonth(), 23, 59, 0 );

Futures.addCallback(

        mClient .getMe()
                .getCalendarView()
                .addParameter("startDateTime", now)
                .addParameter("endDateTime", workDayEnd)
                .read(),
        new FutureCallback<OrcList<Event>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final OrcList<Event> result) {

                // ...

                future.set(myList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
                // ...
                future.setException(t);
            }
        }
);

return future;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If `getBookings` and `setBookings` are both invoked on the UI thread all the time, you should be fine. You know that by the time `isThereAPendingRequest` is set to false, the request must have already completed and therefore you are safe to go. By the way, `Futures.addCallback` has an alternate signature that allows you to explicitly pass in an `Executor`, so if you use that you don't need to call `runOnUiThread` which reduces some code nesting.

However, if you intend to invoke these methods concurrently, I see at least one race condition that requires locks to prevent. More details on that if you're interested.

---

Edit for completeness:

The question states that your goal is to prevent two requests from running at the same time. The are two cases where that can happen:

1. `isThereAPendingRequest==false`, but there is actually a pending request. Your code so far is safe from this, since you only set it to false after the request has been completed. You don't even need `volatile` here.
2. `getBookings` and/or `setBookings` are called on different threads. What happens if they both reach `if(isThereAPendingRequest)` at the same time? They can simultaneously (and correctly) see that it is false, set it to true, then both independently send a request and cause you to crash.

You don't need to worry about (1), and (2) should not be a problem as long as you always invoke those methods on the same thread.

Comment: I've update the question with one of the functions called. In the future I won't have getCalendarEvents though because I'll receive those updates through a BroadcasterReceiver. In that case could that cause problems? Should I just make it volatile to prevent problems? Thanks again